# If $\alpha''$ and $\alpha'$ are collinear, then $\alpha$ is a pre-geodesic.

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to solve exercise $19$ in pages $95$ and $96$ in O'Neill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry book. There are four items and I'm having trouble with the last one.

Let $(M,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Lorentz manifold and $\alpha$ be a regular curve such that $\alpha''(s) = f(s)\alpha'(s)$.

**a)** If $\beta = \alpha\circ h$, $\beta$ is pre-geodesic if and only if $h''+ (f\circ h) (h')^2 = 0$.

Easy, just compute $\beta''(s)=( h''(s) + f( h(s)) (h'(s))^2)\alpha'(h(s))$ and use that $\alpha$ is regular.

**b)** If $\beta$ has unit speed and $\langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle $ is never zero, then $\beta$ is geodesic.

If $\beta$ has unit speed, then $\langle \beta''(s), \beta'(s)\rangle = 0$ for all $s$, after differentiating once, but this evaluates to $h'(s) ( h''(s) + f( h(s)) (h'(s))^2) \langle \alpha'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle = 0$.

**c)** $\langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle$ is always zero or never zero.

From $\langle \alpha'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle' = 2f(s)\langle \alpha'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle$, we have $\langle \alpha'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle = Ce^{2\int f(s)\,{\rm d}s}$. If that is zero in some point it is always zero by uniqueness of solutions of IVP's, and otherwise it is never zero because the exponential is never zero.

**d)** If $\langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle$ is always zero, then $\alpha$ is pre-geodesic.

I'm stuck. The only thing I managed to get is that $\langle \alpha''(s),\alpha''(s)\rangle = 0$. If we could prove that $\alpha''(s)$ is not lightlike, this would imply that $\alpha''(s) = 0 $. Help?

Comment: I may be missing something, but if $0=\langle   \alpha^{\prime\prime},\alpha^{\prime\prime}\rangle = f^2  \langle \alpha^{\prime},\alpha^{\prime}\rangle $ and $\langle \alpha^{\prime},\alpha^{\prime}\rangle\neq 0 $ then $f=0$ and so $\alpha^{\prime\prime}= f \alpha^{\prime}=0$.
If, on the other hand, $f\neq 0$, then the same equations show $\alpha^{\prime\prime}$ is not lightlike.

Comment: @Thomas, I"m sorry, I copied it wrong, the assumption is that $\langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle $ is always zero, and I used that to get $\langle \alpha'',\alpha''\rangle = 0 $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to show in (d) is that if $\langle\alpha',\alpha'\rangle=0$ everywhere, then $\alpha$ is a geodesic up to reparametrization, which is the same as $\alpha''(s)=f(s)\alpha'(s)$ everywhere. This is easy if you have already shown that $\langle\alpha'',\alpha''\rangle=0$ everywhere, for we also have $\langle\alpha',\alpha''\rangle=0$ everywhere. This means that for all $s$ in the domain of $\alpha$ we have that $\alpha''(s)$ is null and orthogonal to $\alpha'(s)$, which is also null. This happens if and only if $\alpha''(s)=f(s)\alpha'(s)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I quite get it. Shouldn't I prove that $\alpha'' = 0$?

Comment: No. This would imply that $\alpha$ is a *geodesic*, which is in general not true. Take for instance a null geodesic $\beta$ and a non-affine reparametrization $g$ (e.g. $g(t)=\tanh t$). Then $\alpha=\beta\circ g$ is a pre-geodesic which is *not* a geodesic, but still $\langle\alpha',\alpha'\rangle=0$ everywhere by the chain rule.

Comment: This example made sense, thanks. I was thinking that being pre-geodesic + constant speed implied being a geodesic. I don't see how $\alpha''(s) = f(s)\alpha'(s)$ is equivalent as being pre-geodesic, though. And again, it seemed that $\alpha''(s) = f(s)\alpha'(s)$ was the hypothesis right from the start. I am confused.

Comment: The hypothesis $\langle\alpha',\alpha'\rangle=0$ doesn't entail constant speed, as my counterexample above shows. To see the aforementioned equivalence, let $\beta:[a,b]\rightarrow M$ be a geodesic, and $g:[c,d]\rightarrow[a,b]$ a diffeomorphism (i.e. a reparametrization). Then $$(\beta\circ g)''(t)=\frac{g''(t)}{g'(t)}(\beta\circ g)'(t)=(\log g'(t))'(\beta\circ g)'(t)$$ for all $t$ by the chain and Leibniz rules, thus yielding $f(t)=(\log g)'(t)$. Reversing the above formula proves the converse statement.

Comment: In my opinion, item (d) is written somewhat imprecisely. (by the way, it should be $f = (\log g')'$ in my previous comment - unfortunately, I can no longer edit it)

Comment: Yes, it is badly written, isn't 100% clear what are the hypothesis. I understood that item (d) goes as: $\langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle = 0 \implies \alpha'' \parallel \alpha ' \implies \alpha$ pre-geodesic, ok. Just two more things and I think I won't bother you anymore.

- how come the hypothesis $\langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle$ doesn't entail constant speed? It is zero, and AFAIK $0$ is a constant :P

- I actually tried to write the converse, but then I got $h = g^{-1}$, where $g(t) = \int e^{\int f(t) \,dt} \,dt$, and I'm probably messing up here. Was it supposed to be this hard?

Comment: $\alpha'(s)$ being null everywhere is not so great a restriction as it seems. Any $s$-dependent rescaling of $\alpha'$ will keep it null, and this is essentially all the freedom we have here. As for your second question, you are correct - the formula is not that pretty indeed, but it is consistent with the fact that affine reparametrizations keep the geodesic character (which amount to the freedom in choosing the constants in the primitives).

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'll try again to write the converse, if anything I'll open another question for that, since it'll boil down to calculus. Thanks a lot for the patience!

Comment: @IvoTerek I'm also reading this book now and happy to find someone else who have read this. So from the comments above, I want to check that if we need to use implicit function theorem to $g(t)=\int e^{\int f(t)\, dt} \, dt$ to solve a local solution $h$ to the ODE in Exercise (a) explicitly and patch local solutions up to get a solution on the whole region where $\alpha$ exists? It seems a bit lengthy for such a question so I'm wondering if there's some more direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 19 asks the reader to show that in a semi-Riemannian manifold, a regular curve $\alpha$ with $α''(s)=f(s)α'(s)$ is pregeodesic.  (That is, it can be reparametrized to be a geodesic.)  This result is needed later in the book in the context of geodesic curves in warped product spaces.

As mentioned in the question, if a reparametrization $h$ satisfies the differential equation in a), it makes $\alpha \circ h$ a geodesic. We can prove the result by solving the differential equation.  The complication is that we need $h$ to be defined so that its range is the whole domain of $\alpha$, and it is strictly increasing.  (Or strictly decreasing.)  Let $(a, b)$ be the domain of $\alpha$.  For any point $s$ in $(a, b)$ we can find a solution $h_s$ of the differential equation on an interval including zero with $h_s(0) = s$ and $h_s'(0) = 1$.  By shrinking the interval we can have $h_s'(t) > 0$ for all $t$ in the domain of $h_s$.  Pick a fixed point $s_0$ in $(a, b)$.  Notice that if $h$ is a solution of the differential equation, then any affine reparametrization of $h$ is also a solution.  Let $[c,d]$ be any closed interval containing $s_0$ and contained in $(a,b)$.  Since $[c,d]$ is compact, the ranges of a finite number of the $h_s$ cover $[c,d]$.  Starting with $h_{s_0}$, we can extend this function with affine reparametrizations of $h_s$ from the finite set to get a solution $h_{[c,d]}$ whose range is an open interval containing $[c,d]$, and which is strictly increasing.  Since for different $[c,d]$ these solutions agree at $s_0$, any two agree on their common domain.  We can then glue them together to get a solution whose range is $(a, b)$.  This shows that $\alpha$ is pregeodesic as desired.